# Given an input image of 128x128, and output 29x29. What is the size of the area of the input that is middle pix in output

Tags: convolution, machine-learning, neural-networks

> > Given an input image of 128x128, after putting it through a convolutional neural network the output is 29x29. What is the size of the area (in pixels) of the input that correspond to the middle pixel in the output?

I was thinking it had to do with 128/29 = 4.4. Each pixel in the output corresponds to 4 pixels in the input but that doesn't get me near the right answer.

Thank you!

Comment: You need to square that.  How many pixels are in the input?  How many in the output?

Comment: the input image 128x128

Comment: That's not what I meant.  There are $128^2$ pixels in the input and $29^2$ in the output.  Those are the numbers you need to be concerned with.